# Run multiple https docker containers with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

My goal is to up and running multiple containers on docker with https using asp net webapi. So far I successufully ran one webapi container with https followed steps in this article:

[Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

When I try to add https to second container while sending request my second webapi container stops when first container works as expected.

How to achieve adding https certificate to all asp net webapi containers?

My docker-compose.yml looks like below:

```yaml
# Please refer https://aka.ms/HTTPSinContainer on how to setup an https developer certificate for your ASP .NET Core service.

version: '3.4'

services:

  app1:
    image: app1
    container_name: app1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: source/app1/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 6000:5000
      - 6001:443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:6001
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro

  app2:
    image: app2
    container_name: app2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: source/app2/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 6002:5000
      - 6003:443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:6003
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

and `Dockerfile` of `app1`:

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["source/app1/app1.csproj", "source/app1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "source/app1/app1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/source/app1"
RUN dotnet build "app1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "app1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app1.dll"]
```

and `Dockerfile` of `app2`:

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["source/app2/app2.csproj", "source/app2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "source/app2/app2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/source/app2"
RUN dotnet build "app2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "app2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app2.dll"]
```